# Subtract Characters One at a Time

Tags: java

I am trying to get the following code to delete the last character one at a time until the last...
Output:
Will
Wil
Wi
W

```
 * @author Will
 */
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class DecreaseLetters {

public static void main(String args[]){

    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Anota una Frase: ");
    String input=s.nextLine();
    return str.substring(0,str.length()-1);
    System.out.println(input);
}
}
```

Comment: Does your code compile?

Comment: this code wont even compile, what is str

Comment: How do you have  `return` statement in this main method? Also, the sysout after return statement? Your code won't compile.

Comment: Correct the code wont compile.. Sorry was working on another method...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class DecreaseLetters {

public static void main(String args[]){

Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Anota una Frase: ");
String str=s.nextLine();
while(str.length()>1) {
    str =  str.substring(0,str.length()-1);     
    System.out.println(str.substring(0,str.length()-1));
     }

   }
}
```

Reverse:

```
   Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Anota una Frase: ");
String str=s.nextLine();
int i = 0;
while(i<=str.length()) {
    String str2 =  str.substring(0,i);      
    System.out.println(str2);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Thank You... How about if we wanted to invert this say we start with a K then Ka Kar Karl Karla...

Comment: I've edited for reverse, put the 2nd code into main()

Answer (score 1):

Java `String` is immutable. You could use a `StringBuilder` like,

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Anota una Frase: ");
String input = s.nextLine();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input);
while (sb.length() > 0) {
    System.out.print(sb);
    System.out.print(" ");
    sb.setLength(sb.length() - 1);
}
System.out.println();
```

**or**, you could produce substrings in a loop like

```
for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
    System.out.print(input.substring(0, input.length() - i));
    System.out.print(" ");
}
System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a for loop and the `substring()` function of the String class:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    System.out.println("Anota una Frase: ");
    String text = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();

    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
        System.out.println(text.substring(0, text.length()-i));
}
```

Comment: Is your answer verified?